# Changing layout with wp_customise

Tags: php, customization, loop

So I'm trying to build a conditional statement to display different layouts depending on the option selected.

Having a bit of trouble.

```
$wp_customize->add_setting('layout', array(
  'default'           => 'stream',
  )); // add our default setting.
$wp_customize->add_control('layout', array(
  'label'      => __('Select layout', 'Ari'),
  'section'    => 'layout',
  'settings'   => 'layout',
  'type'       => 'radio',
  'choices'    => array(
    'stream'   => 'Stream',
    'grid'  => 'Grid',
  ),
)); // use radio buttons with (so far) two choices.
```

So here we have a couple of choices.

```
$wp_customize->add_section('layout' , array(
    'title' => __('Layout','Ari'),
)); // add our layout section in the customize panel.
```

Displaying our layout.

```
    <?php if ( get_theme_mod( 'stream' ) ) : ?>
    <p>stream</p> if ( have_posts() ) etc 
    <?php elseif ( get_theme_mod( 'grid' ) ) : ?>
    <p>grid</p> // if ( have_posts() )  etc
    <?php else : //Nothing ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Just...nothing. I've trawled through the codex and I can't see what I'm doing wrong. It just doesn't show any output.

What about get_setting? How would  I write a conditional for that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check against the value of `layout`:

```
if ( get_theme_mod( 'layout' ) === 'stream' ) {
    // Stream
} elseif ( get_theme_mod( 'layout' ) === 'grid' ) {
    // Grid
} else {
    // Fallback
}
```

Comment: Don't you need an endif?

Comment: Wait nvm I'm being an idiot. `}` duh. Is this the correct/best way to do it, btw? Seems like there's lots of different ways to mess with the customize options.

Comment: Looks okay to me.